# Noise in Arduino BLE Data Reading

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

The characters I got for Arduino BLE characteristics reading are always tailed with some random characters. For example, the printing should ends with `"test string"` but it actually print out `"test string       !"` The tailing string is randomized based on different string being sent.

Any suggestions for resolving this issue?

The code for reading character is the following:

```
void incomingCharacteristicWritten(BLEDevice central, BLECharacteristic characteristic) {
  byte value[characteristic.valueLength()];
  incomingDataCharacteristic.readValue(value, characteristic.valueLength());
  Serial.print("Characteristic event, written: ");
  Serial.print((char *) value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`readValue()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/arduinoble/blecharacteristic.readvalue/) writes to a buffer of bytes, which is NOT the same as a null-terminated C string. So by simply casting the buffer to a `char *` and printing it, the `print()` function will stop when it encounters the first null character. This may be soon or late, depending on what arbitrary contents you have in memory. This explains the random characters you've observed.

To fix this, either print the bytes one at a time in a loop, convert it to a C++ string, or make sure to null-terminate it.

For example, the following should work:

```cpp
void incomingCharacteristicWritten(BLEDevice central, BLECharacteristic characteristic) {
  int length = characteristic.valueLength();
  byte value[length + 1];  // one byte more, to save the '\0' character!
  incomingDataCharacteristic.readValue(value, length);
  value[length] = '\0';  // make sure to null-terminate!
  Serial.print("Characteristic event, written: ");
  Serial.print((char *) value);
}
```